# Is this a bug from IE or from my code? - "Waiting for http://mysite.com"

Tags: internet-explorer, freeze, titlebar

When I access my page, the title is loaded properly, but after a second, it changes to "Waiting for http://example.com".

The page loads, but even after everything is loaded, the title continues, but only in the IE tab, because in the tray the title is as it should be.

PS:It does not happens with Chrome. And the I.E version is 10
Image of the issue:
[image]

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico" />

        <title>DataTables Editor example</title>
        <style class="include" type="text/css">
            @import "support/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css";
            @import "support/bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css";
            @import "css/customTable.css";
        </style>

        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../media/js/dataTables.editor.js"></script>

        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.editor.bootstrap.js"></script>

        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/custom.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="c_body">
        <div class="mContainer">
            <div id="dt_div">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered display" id="example">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Data</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Tema</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">V&iacute;nculo</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Empresa</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Sub contratada</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">NDP</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">CH</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">HHT</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Ger&ecirc;ncia</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">&Aacute;rea Solicitante</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">CC</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Rateio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft has acknowledged the issue as a bug in IE10. The issue is closed with status "Won't Fix". 
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/787208/ie10-waiting-for-domains-url-text-occasionally-gets-stuck-on-tabs-title-only-after-refreshing-it

It is also a known bug in IE11.

Comment: Is there any solution to fix it ?

Answer (score 7):

Odd as it may seem I managed to fix it for ie8 without apparently causing any damage to Firefox or Chrome by using this in JavaScript

```
 <script language="javascript">
  window.onfocus = function(){
  var title_var = document.title;
  document.title = title_var;
  }
 </script>
```

As Charly H suggests onload could also be used

```
 <script language="javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
  var title_var = document.title;
  document.title = title_var;
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: I know this post is 1 year old already, but for other people looking for a fix, changing window.onfocus to window.onload is a better solution. But still a nice solution to this Problem.

Comment: This was the original full script on the post by notawizard. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/slider-glitch-after-clicking-on-other-browser-tabs  For just this part you are probably right, onload would be better. Amazingly it has still not been fixed in Edge. (notawizard is me on WordPress)

Comment: Further experimentation revealed that 'onfocus()' was more reliable as when tabs were switched it triggered the 'onfocus()' event but not necessarily an  'onload()' event.

Comment: Also in Firefox at the time it kept reloading when I used window.onload which it didn't do with on.focus